# Excluding layers from snapping using IPointSnapper

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, snapping

I'm working with ArcObjects in C#, and am trying to exclude all map layers but one (the only one I want to snap to) from the snapping environment. I'm using the ISnappingEnvironment and IPointSnapper interfaces. I've put the following code in the OnClick method of the tool I'm using:

```
 m_Snapper = m_SnappingEnvironment.PointSnapper;
 ISet anExclLyrSet = new SetClass();
 m_Snapper.ExcludedLayers(ref anExclLyrSet);

 // ...loop through all map layers, adding all but the one of interest to anExclLyrSet

 m_Snapper.ClearCache();
```

Basically, I'm getting poor snapping performance due to the presence of a basemap layer that contains multiple feature layers. If I turn that layer off (make invisible), the performance is good.

I've confirmed that all the layers (for composite type layers, I add each sub-layer to the exclusion as well) are being added to the exclusion set, but I can't seem to get the performance to improve without turning off that basemap layer. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - does the cache need to be cleared after each individual layer is excluded? I'd appreciate insights anyone might have regarding this. Thanks!

Mark C.

Comment: What happens if you don't use a composite layer but just have each of its children as regular (orphan) layers, does performance improve?

Comment: I think exclusion only works on classic snapping. I don't nknow about the ipointsnapper. but if there is a classic method on isnappingenvironment that would probably be the way to go.

Comment: @Kirk, I'm working with Mark on this project, and we would rather not change the map layer structure. Is there a reason you think performance would improve with that change to the map?

Comment: @Keith If you take he grouplayer out of the equation, but promote the child layers to standalone layers, and the performance improves, I think you could narrow it down to an issue (and perhaps a bug) with group layers. Also, maybe excluding a grouplayer implicitly excludes all the children, so maybe also try excluding just the group layer and not the children.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution we settled on for this problem. It is called when the snapping environment is setup.

```
/// <summary>
/// Builds (adds layers) to the exclusion set for IPointSnapper. Set up to exclude all
/// layers except the one with the supplied name.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="aMap"> Reference to the map. </param>
/// <param name="anExclLyrSet"> Reference to the layer exclusion set for IPointSnapper. </param>
/// <param name="aStr"> Name of the one layer NOT to exclude. </param>
/// <param name="pSnapper"> Reference to the PointSnapper. </param>
public static void BuildSnappingExclusionSet(IMap aMap, ref ISet anExclLyrSet, string aStr, IPointSnapper pSnapper)
{
    ILayer aLyr = null;
    ICompositeLayer aCompLyr = null;
    IBasemapLayer aBmapLyr = null;
    IBasemapSubLayer aBmapSubLyr = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < aMap.LayerCount; i++)
    {
        aLyr = aMap.get_Layer(i);
        try     // Will work if this is some type of composite layer
        {
            aCompLyr = (ICompositeLayer)aLyr;
            aBmapLyr = (IBasemapLayer)aLyr;
            if (aBmapLyr != null) // basemap layer - must process differently
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < aCompLyr.Count; j++)
                {
                    aBmapSubLyr = (IBasemapSubLayer)aCompLyr.get_Layer(j);
                    aLyr = aBmapSubLyr.Layer;
                    if (aLyr.Name != aStr)
                        anExclLyrSet.Add(aBmapSubLyr.Layer);
                }
            }
            else // otherwise, process as an ordinary composite layer
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < aCompLyr.Count; j++)
                {
                    aLyr = aCompLyr.get_Layer(j);
                    if (aLyr.Name != aStr)
                        anExclLyrSet.Add(aLyr);
                }
            }
        }
        catch  // Implies not a composite layer - simply add to exclusion
        {
            if (aLyr.Name != aStr)
                anExclLyrSet.Add(aLyr);
        }

        pSnapper.ClearCache();
    }
}
```